# How to update state value on login

Tags: vue.js, vuex

How do I update state value on login. So that I can use the same state in the main page.

account.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const account = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
  id : 0
},
mutations: {
    setId(state, id) {
        state.id = id
    }
},
actions: {
  async actionA ({ commit }) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              commit('setId', 33)
              resolve()
            }, 1000)
          })
   }
}
});
```

I need to update the value of id in login.js and use this value in home.vue.

```
store.dispatch('actionA').then(() => {
    console.log('success');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components

```js
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'addItems', // map `this.addItems()` to `this.$store.dispatch('addItems')`
    ]),
  }
}
```

And on your login button:

```html
<button @click="addItems('your-id-here')">Log In</button>
```

Comment: I need to update the value from a js file. How do I do that?

Comment: Call  ̀this.addItems`